# Cant connect to windows pptp vpn in Xenial but no problem in Precise

Tags: 16.04, vpn, pptp

I have Precise installation with VPN client that can connect to some Windows server PPTP vpn without any problem.
Moving to Xenial I have copied settings and keyring, all ok and I can connect to VPN services on linux servers.
Anyway, I can not reach Windows server PPTP vpn anyhow I try.
Please, point me to something I may have missed, something like mppe or what package I may have missed?

I put sysylog here either from Precise that works, then Xenial that dont (drops link after receiving IP).

`Jun 26 09:38:31 Acer daemon.info NetworkManager[972]:  VPN plugin state changed: starting (3)
Jun 26 09:38:31 Acer daemon.info NetworkManager[972]:  VPN connection XXX (Connect) reply received.
Jun 26 09:38:31 Acer local2.info pppd[16387]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.5/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
Jun 26 09:38:31 Acer local2.notice pppd[16387]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Jun 26 09:38:31 Acer daemon.notice pptp[16392]: nm-pptp-service-16368 log[main:pptp.c:314]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated
Jun 26 09:38:32 Acer daemon.notice pptp[16400]: nm-pptp-service-16368 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 1 'Start-Control-Connection-Request'
Jun 26 09:38:32 Acer local2.info pppd[16387]: Using interface ppp0
Jun 26 09:38:32 Acer local2.notice pppd[16387]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/2
Jun 26 09:38:32 Acer daemon.notice NetworkManager[972]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Jun 26 09:38:32 Acer daemon.notice NetworkManager[972]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Jun 26 09:38:32 Acer daemon.notice pptp[16400]: nm-pptp-service-16368 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:739]: Received Start Control Connection Reply
Jun 26 09:38:32 Acer daemon.notice pptp[16400]: nm-pptp-service-16368 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:773]: Client connection established.
Jun 26 09:38:33 Acer daemon.notice pptp[16400]: nm-pptp-service-16368 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 7 'Outgoing-Call-Request'
Jun 26 09:38:33 Acer daemon.notice pptp[16400]: nm-pptp-service-16368 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:858]: Received Outgoing Call Reply.
Jun 26 09:38:33 Acer daemon.notice pptp[16400]: nm-pptp-service-16368 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:897]: Outgoing call established (call ID 0, peer's call ID 26100).
Jun 26 09:38:33 Acer daemon.notice pptp[16400]: nm-pptp-service-16368 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:950]: PPTP_SET_LINK_INFO received from peer_callid 0
Jun 26 09:38:33 Acer daemon.notice pptp[16400]: nm-pptp-service-16368 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:953]:   send_accm is 00000000, recv_accm is FFFFFFFF
Jun 26 09:38:33 Acer daemon.warn pptp[16400]: nm-pptp-service-16368 warn[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:956]: Non-zero Async Control Character Maps are not supported!
Jun 26 09:38:33 Acer local2.notice pppd[16387]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Jun 26 09:38:33 Acer user.info kernel: [  195.269004] PPP MPPE Compression module registered
Jun 26 09:38:33 Acer local2.notice pppd[16387]: MPPE 128-bit stateless compression enabled
Jun 26 09:38:35 Acer local2.notice pppd[16387]: local  IP address 10.150.0.131
Jun 26 09:38:35 Acer local2.notice pppd[16387]: remote IP address 10.150.0.163
Jun 26 09:38:35 Acer local2.notice pppd[16387]: primary   DNS address 10.150.0.11
Jun 26 09:38:35 Acer local2.notice pppd[16387]: secondary DNS address 10.150.0.12
Jun 26 09:38:35 Acer daemon.info NetworkManager[972]:  VPN connection XXX (IP Config Get) reply received.
Jun 26 09:38:35 Acer daemon.info NetworkManager[972]:  VPN Gateway: aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa
Jun 26 09:38:35 Acer daemon.info NetworkManager[972]:  Tunnel Device: ppp0
Jun 26 09:38:35 Acer daemon.info NetworkManager[972]:  Internal IP4 Address: 10.150.0.131
Jun 26 09:38:35 Acer daemon.info NetworkManager[972]:  Internal IP4 Prefix: 32
Jun 26 09:38:35 Acer daemon.info NetworkManager[972]:  Internal IP4 Point-to-Point Address: 10.150.0.163
Jun 26 09:38:35 Acer daemon.info NetworkManager[972]:  Maximum Segment Size (MSS): 0
Jun 26 09:38:35 Acer daemon.info NetworkManager[972]:  Forbid Default Route: no
Jun 26 09:38:35 Acer daemon.info NetworkManager[972]:  Internal IP4 DNS: 10.150.0.11
Jun 26 09:38:35 Acer daemon.info NetworkManager[972]:  Internal IP4 DNS: 10.150.0.12
Jun 26 09:38:35 Acer daemon.info NetworkManager[972]:  DNS Domain: '(none)'`

_________ now the Xenial log that drops:

`Jun 26 10:10:58 Acer local2.info pppd[2263]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.7/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
Jun 26 10:10:58 Acer local2.notice pppd[2263]: pppd 2.4.7 started by root, uid 0
Jun 26 10:10:58 Acer local2.info pppd[2263]: Using interface ppp0
Jun 26 10:10:58 Acer local2.notice pppd[2263]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/4
Jun 26 10:10:58 Acer daemon.notice pptp[2271]: nm-pptp-service-2255 log[main:pptp.c:350]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated
Jun 26 10:10:58 Acer daemon.notice pptp[2283]: nm-pptp-service-2255 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:259]: Sent control packet type is 1 'Start-Control-Connection-Request'
Jun 26 10:10:58 Acer daemon.notice pptp[2283]: nm-pptp-service-2255 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:781]: Received Start Control Connection Reply
Jun 26 10:10:58 Acer daemon.notice pptp[2283]: nm-pptp-service-2255 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:815]: Client connection established.
Jun 26 10:10:59 Acer daemon.notice pptp[2283]: nm-pptp-service-2255 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:259]: Sent control packet type is 7 'Outgoing-Call-Request'
Jun 26 10:10:59 Acer daemon.notice pptp[2283]: nm-pptp-service-2255 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:900]: Received Outgoing Call Reply.
Jun 26 10:10:59 Acer daemon.notice pptp[2283]: nm-pptp-service-2255 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:939]: Outgoing call established (call ID 7146, peer's call ID 38683).
Jun 26 10:10:59 Acer daemon.notice pptp[2283]: nm-pptp-service-2255 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:1003]: PPTP_SET_LINK_INFO received from peer_callid 7146
Jun 26 10:10:59 Acer daemon.notice pptp[2283]: nm-pptp-service-2255 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:1006]:   send_accm is 00000000, recv_accm is FFFFFFFF
Jun 26 10:10:59 Acer daemon.warn pptp[2283]: nm-pptp-service-2255 warn[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:1009]: Non-zero Async Control Character Maps are not supported!
Jun 26 10:10:59 Acer local2.notice pppd[2263]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Jun 26 10:10:59 Acer local2.notice pppd[2263]: MPPE 128-bit stateless compression enabled
Jun 26 10:11:01 Acer local2.notice pppd[2263]: local  IP address 10.150.0.157
Jun 26 10:11:01 Acer local2.notice pppd[2263]: remote IP address 10.150.0.163
Jun 26 10:11:01 Acer local2.notice pppd[2263]: primary   DNS address 10.150.0.11
Jun 26 10:11:01 Acer local2.notice pppd[2263]: secondary DNS address 10.150.0.12
Jun 26 10:11:01 Acer local2.info pppd[2263]: Terminating on signal 15
Jun 26 10:11:01 Acer local2.info pppd[2263]: Connect time 0.0 minutes.
Jun 26 10:11:01 Acer local2.info pppd[2263]: Sent 0 bytes, received 234 bytes.
Jun 26 10:11:01 Acer local2.err pppd[2263]: MPPE disabled
Jun 26 10:11:01 Acer local2.warn pppd[2263]: Child process /usr/sbin/pptp aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa --nolaunchpppd --loglevel 0 --logstring nm-pptp-service-2255 (pid 2267) terminated with signal 15
Jun 26 10:11:01 Acer daemon.notice pptp[2283]: nm-pptp-service-2255 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:1003]: PPTP_SET_LINK_INFO received from peer_callid 7146
Jun 26 10:11:01 Acer daemon.notice pptp[2283]: nm-pptp-service-2255 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:1006]:   send_accm is FFFFFFFF, recv_accm is FFFFFFFF
Jun 26 10:11:01 Acer daemon.warn pptp[2283]: nm-pptp-service-2255 warn[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:1009]: Non-zero Async Control Character Maps are not supported!
Jun 26 10:11:01 Acer local2.notice pppd[2263]: Connection terminated.
Jun 26 10:11:01 Acer local2.info pppd[2263]: Exit.
Jun 26 10:11:01 Acer daemon.warn pptp[2271]: nm-pptp-service-2255 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:220]: short read (-1): Input/output error
Jun 26 10:11:01 Acer daemon.warn pptp[2271]: nm-pptp-service-2255 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:232]: pppd may have shutdown, see pppd log
Jun 26 10:11:01 Acer daemon.notice pptp[2283]: nm-pptp-service-2255 log[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:245]: Closing connection (unhandled)
Jun 26 10:11:01 Acer daemon.notice pptp[2283]: nm-pptp-service-2255 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:259]: Sent control packet type is 12 'Call-Clear-Request'
Jun 26 10:11:01 Acer daemon.notice pptp[2283]: nm-pptp-service-2255 log[call_callback:pptp_callmgr.c:84]: Closing connection (call state)`

---

Well I found some error about adding a route in the kernel log after posting this question:

`Jun 24 11:57:43 Acer NetworkManager[784]:   [1466762263.7519] vpn-connection[0x28365d0,ed191654-0ebe-423d-b047-4e6b0b5054a1,XXX,6:(ppp0)]: VPN plugin: state changed: started (4)
Jun 24 11:57:43 Acer NetworkManager[784]:  [1466762263.7639] platform-linux: do-add-ip4-route[6: 10.150.0.0/24 10]: failure 101 (Network is unreachable)
Jun 24 11:57:43 Acer NetworkManager[784]:  [1466762263.7640] platform-linux: do-add-ip4-route[6: 192.168.100.0/24 10]: failure 101 (Network is unreachable)
Jun 24 11:57:43 Acer NetworkManager[784]:   [1466762263.7655] vpn-connection[0x28365d0,ed191654-0ebe-423d-b047-4e6b0b5054a1,XXX,6:(ppp0)]: VPN connection: did not receive valid IP config information
Jun 24 11:57:43 Acer NetworkManager[784]:  [1466762263.7961] platform-linux: do-change-link[6]: failure changing link: failure 19 (No such device)
Jun 24 11:57:43 Acer NetworkManager[784]:   [1466762263.7993] vpn-connection[0x28365d0,ed191654-0ebe-423d-b047-4e6b0b5054a1,XXX,0]: VPN service disappeared
Jun 24 11:57:43 Acer NetworkManager[784]:   [1466762263.8017] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Jun 24 11:58:13 Acer NetworkManager[784]:   [1466762293.3600] DNS: starting dnsmasq...`

- removed ALL routes and connection started to work.
  Marking the question answered..

  - Anyway, Iam curious what is different in Xenial, since I did file-copy of Network-manager configs so it was not just a typo.

Comment: Have you tried enabling mppe-stateful on the advanced settings for pptp?

Comment: Yes I have, I did try changing also compression options one-by-one but none had any effect.

Comment: Noticed this in kernel log:  \n  <error> [1466762263.7639] platform-linux: do-add-ip4-route[6: 10.150.0.0/24 10]: failure 101 (Network is unreachable)
<error> [1466762263.7640] platform-linux: do-add-ip4-route[6: 192.168.100.0/24 10]: failure 101 (Network is unreachable)
<warn>  [1466762263.7655] vpn-connection[0x28365d0,ed191654-0ebe-423d-b047-4e6b0b5054a1,XXX,6:(ppp0)]: VPN connection: did not receive valid IP config information
 <error> [1466762263.7961] platform-linux: do-change-link[6]: failure changing link: failure 19 (No such device)

Comment: Try enabling pppd debug and check the ipcp negotiation. Do: `sudo service network-manager stop` and then run it with pppd debug: `NM_PPP_DEBUG=1 sudo NetworkManager --no-daemon`

Comment: Thank You.  PPP seems to say nothing wrong, but I found that it is a route setting (which worked in Precise) what  cause connection drop. I tried to add it manualy (via nm gui) again, and it causes conn drop again, so it must be something to investigate. (and workaround is to let all traffic pass vpn).